# viewParam with parametername fromName doesn't work

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, viewparams

I have the following in my code:

```
<f:viewParam name="from_name" value="#{bean.fromName}" />
```

And this parameter doesn't work. I'm absolutely convinced that the getters and setters behind `bean.fromName` are correct. Yet this parameter doesn't work, while all the other similar parameters in the same file do. If I rename `bean.fromName` to `bean.xfromName` and adjust the getters and setters it works. Is fromName a special JSF viewParam value?

Note:

```
xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
```

Comment: You need to specify your JSF implementation and version. Also have you tried launching your project from outside eclipse or whatever IDE you're using? It might be messing up everything.

Comment: _"Is fromName a special JSF viewParam value?"_ No it is not. [mcve] please. And try running your application in development mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your `<f:viewParam>` tag inside some `<f:metadata>` tags ?

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="from_name" value="#{bean.fromName}" />
</f:metadata>
```

Comment: Yes it is, just like the ones you wrote down.